# Page Keeps echo "Front Page Rather than "Member Access"

Tags: php

I have this login form based on "token" validation while everything seems to working fine it always echo "Front Page Rather than "Member Access".
I have the error reporting on.

```
<body>
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        include('test.php');

        $login = new login();

        if($login->isLoggedIn())
            header('location: home.php');
        else
            $login->showErrors();
    }
    $token = $_SESSION['token'] = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(),true));
    ?>  

    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <table>
            <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="username" /></td></td>
            <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password" /></td></td>
        </table>
        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo "$token"; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
</body>
```

And, test php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

class login
{
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
private $_id;
private $_username;
private $_password;
private $_passwordmd5;
}
private $_errors;
private $_access;
private $_login;
private $_token;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->_errors = array();
    $this->_login = isset($_POST['login'])? 1 : 0;
    $this->_access = 0;
    $this->_token = $_POST['token'];

    $this->_id = 0;
    $this->_username = ($this->_login)? $this->filter($_POST['username']) : $_SESSION['username'];
    $this->_password = ($this->_login)? $this->filter($_POST['password']) : '';
    $this->_passwordmd5 = ($this->_login)? md5($this->_password) : $_SESSION['password'];
}

public function isLoggedIn()
{
    ($this->_login)? $this->verifyPost() : $this->verifySession();
    return $this->_access;
}

public function filter($var)
{
    return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/','',$var);
}

public function verifyPost()
{
    try
    {
        if(!$this->isTokenValid())
            throw new exception('Invalid Form Token');

        if(!$this->isDataValid())
            throw new exception('Invalid Username & Password Criteria');

        if(!$this->verifyDatabase())
            throw new exception('Not able to connect');

        $this->_access=1;
        $this->registerSession();
    }
    catch (exception $e)
    {
    $this->_errors[] = $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function verifySession()
{
if($this->sessionExist() && $this->verifyDatabase())
 $this->_access = 1;
}

public function verifyDatabase()
{
// Database Connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","","");
if (!$con) { die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($con));}
$db_select=mysqli_select_db($con, "");
if (!$db_select) { die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error($con));}

$data = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$this->_username' AND password='$this->_passwordmd5'";

if (mysqli_num_rows($con, $data) == 0)
 {
 list($this->_id) = @array_values(mysqli_fetch_assoc($data));
 return true;
 }
else
 { return false; }

}

public function isDataValid()
{
return (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9](5-15)$/',$this->_username) && preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9](5-20)$/',$this->_password))? 0 : 1;
}

public function isTokenValid()
{
return (!isset($_SESSION['token']) || $this->_token != $_SESSION['token'])? 0 : 1;
}

public function registerSession()
{
$_SESSION['ID'] = $this->_id;
$_SESSION['username'] = $this->_username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $this->_passwordmd5;
}

public function sessionExist()
{
return (!isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['password']))? 1 : 0;
}

public function showErrors()
{
echo "<h3>Errors</h3>";

foreach($this->_errors as $key=>$value)
    echo $value."<br>";
}
}
?>
```

Home php:

```
session_start();
include('test.php');

$login = new login();

if($login->isLoggedIn())
echo "Member Access";
else echo
"Front Page";
```

Looking someone willing to help.

Comment: is the session started?

Comment: @vinay, thanks.. if you mean if session_start(); added in test.php.. yes
ob_start();
session_start();

Comment: `isLoggedIn()` definition ?

Comment: Try inclusing the test.php outside the if condition and try

Comment: change Public  to public and also post your full code

Comment: @Rakesh, I just posted the full code

Comment: Thanks all for your help.. if you are still there, May I get some help on page only echoes "Front Page" Rather than "Member Access"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `isTokenValid` is returning the opposite of what it should. Essentially you have:

```
return $invalidToken ? 1 : 0;
```

Returning `1` if the token doesn't match. Reverse it to `? 0 : 1;` or simplify and return boolean:

```
return isset($_SESSION['token']) && $this->_token === $_SESSION['token'];
```

Comment: Thanks @Wesley, It seemed to work untill I got another error..
 mysqli_num_rows() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in line 80

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows` accepts a mysqli result, not a query/string to execute. You need to fetch the result of the query in `$data`.  Also  make sure to escape `$this->_username` and you probably need to remove the `()` around it.

Comment: Thanks again @Wesley.. I did that and it worked.. Finally if you are still there, May I get some help on page only echoes "Front Page Rather than "Member Access"?